# Scroll To Top on tabBarOnPress

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How is it possible to make the screen scroll to top when the tab bar label is pressed? I am using createMaterialTopTabNavigator from react-navigation version 4.X.

I suspect that the way to do this is to do something inside tabBarOnPress, but I just can't figure out what! Here's a Snack to work with: https://snack.expo.dev/URMUVXUXxw

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of importing ScrollView from `react-native`, import the ScrollView from `react-navigation`. I'm not sure how this fixes the problem, but it does :)